# Move featured area to archive page in canard wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using canard theme for wordpress blog which shows top posts in featured content area.
I have some categories on my blog here is link for [blog](http://blog.edgrab.com)

Use featured content area on category listing(`archive.php`) page, where all top post of that category should appear in `featured content area`.

I tried to edit my archive page,but some css is not working properly I guess, i'm unable to find out where I'm going wrong

```
   <?php
    /**
    * The template for displaying archive pages.
    *
    * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
    *
    * @package Canard
    */

 get_header(); ?>

<div class="site-content-inner">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
     <?php 
       if ( is_archive() ) {
          get_template_part( 'featured-content','archive' );
     }?>
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                ?>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
   </div><!-- .site-content-inner -->

   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: We can't look at where is CSS missed up.
Would you pleas provide some screenshot for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked teh blog page is not coded from this archive page. It does not contain all sections that blog page have. Blog page is coming from some other file.

You can remove post from featured attribute thus it will show only simple posts. If you select post as featured thus they show at top.If no featured post thus not shown as grid at top.

Thanks Hope this is helpful for you.